# Blank Data when Uploading Form Using enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have an interesting problem.  I'm trying to upload a form by way of

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/myendpoint/:id">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="mydata" />
    <input type="file" name="formname" />
</form>
```

... and my remote method call:

```
Patient.uploadVideo = function(id, mydata, cb) {
    console.log(mydata);
    return cb(null, { id: 123 });
};


MyModel.remoteMethod(
'uploadVideo',
{
  http: {path: '/:id/recording/:recordingid/videos', verb: 'post'},
  accepts: [
            {arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true},
            {arg: 'mydata', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'body'}},
           ]
  }
);
```

Unfortunately the body is coming in as blank

How do I get the form data?  I modified server/datasources.json to include

```
"storage": {
    "name": "storage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./server/storage"
}
```

Still nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So unfortunately the documentation is very limited when discussing how to upload files.  There is one reference to the module "loopback-component-storage", one has to tear into it in order to find this diamond in the rough.

```
var storage     =   require('loopback-component-storage');

MyModel.myFunction = function(req, res, options, cb) {
    var storage     =   require('loopback-component-storage');
    var storageService  = storage.StorageService({provider: 'filesystem', root: '/tmp'});

    storageService.upload(req, res, { container: 'upload' }, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data); // this provides a nice object with all of the variables and data wrt the file that was uploaded
        /// ..etc
    });
 };
 MyModel.remoteMethod(
    'myFunction',
    {
        http: {path: '/mypath', verb: 'post'},
        accepts: [
          {arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}},
          {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}}
        ],
        returns: {arg: 'something', type: 'object'}
    }
);
```

You can find the documentation for StorageService [here](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-component-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance. I got file upload working with loopback and angular 2, which considering how small the documentation is for those two is a huge feat. A few expansions:

In `MyModel.myFunction = function(req, res, options, cb) {`, the `options` is not strictly necessary. You can just pass any desired options as a "property"  of the formData object that one would likely pass into `req` object. In your example, if `options` is not passed into the function, but only the formData, then `cb` will not be assigned and will bork the entire call.

If anyone wants to know how I achieved this, the main calls are:

### Angular 2

**upload-test.component.ts**

```
let file = event.srcElement.files[0];
let formData:FormData = new FormData();

this.forumPostService.uploadFile(formData).subscribe(
    response => {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

**upload-test.service.ts**

```
uploadFile(formData: FormData) {
    //LEAVE HEADERS BLANK. LOOPBACK CALL BORKS IF ASSIGNED!
    let headers = new Headers();
    return this.http
        .post('http://apiUrl/myModel/uploadTest',
            formData,
            {headers: headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

"formData", which holds the file, is passed into "req" in http request to loopback API

### Loopback

**uploadTest.js**

```
myModel.uploadTest = function(req, res, callback) {
    var storage = require('loopback-component-storage');
    //"root:'/'" will point to home drive, e.g. 'C://'
    var storageService = storage.StorageService({provider:'filesystem', root:'/'});
    /*"upload" will give e.g. 'C://upload', make sure this folder exists, 
    it wont create it for you*/
    storageService.upload(req, res, { container: 'upload'}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data.files.file[0]);
            callback(null, data.files.file[0]);
        }
    });
}

PostSections.remoteMethod(
    'uploadTest',{
        accepts: [
            {arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}},
            {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}}
        ],
        returns: [
            { arg: 'Result', type: 'object' }
        ],
        http: { path: '/uploadTest', verb: 'post'}
    }
);
```